# How to find an expected value of a conditional probability?

Tags: r

I'm new to R programming and I was just trying this question out online.

Let's say there's two positive integers with a < b , and c be a positive real number.
Now let X be a Poisson random variable with mean c.

And then let Y be the even that X is less than b and divisible by a

How to write code to determine the expected value of E(X|Y).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You're using the R-tag. Lets have a closer look at it together: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks.** For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Since you're new to R programming, you might not be able to write proper R code to do the simulation, but you should be able to write "pseudo-code" for it, e.g. "Simulate n values of X from the unconditional distribution".  We'll help you to translate that into R code.